# Android app reminders

Tags: android, android-activity

For my app that I am writing, I would like the users to be able to set a reminder for an upcoming event (could be days, weeks or months in advance).

I wonder what's the best way to go about it.

1. Have the app handle the reminder natively? Or
2. Have the app feed an alarm event into the android alarm clock (is this even possible?) Or
3. Have the app feed the event into google calendar (again, is this even possible?)

Are there even other options beyond these three?

How should I decide what's the best way to handle reminders such as this (by the way, is there a specific term in android for reminders like this?)

I tried googling *"android app reminders"* and variations thereof without much success.

Answer (score 0):

> remind natively

In order to do this, you'll need to use the `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` or some type of service which can get updates (GCM).

> use alarms

Possible, but you have to manage and set them, particularly across reboots. This article should help: http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/

> use calendar

Can be done, but your app will require the calendar permission and will have to work with the existing provider.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution for the 1st choice is like that create a Android service that checks if any upcoming event exists in SQL-Lite database table which gets the event data from GCM. If exists than notify user. Make this notification clickable to open your application related activiy with sound. Make this event check from table in every some seconds or minutes or etc.

 If an event is only for the user (not shared by others) you don't have to use GCM.